# If and Statement based on reference to 1st cell

Tags: if-statement, cell

I am trying to find a solution to If cell is >1 and the cell below is blank (""), then insert formula into specific cell location.

Sub InsertSlopeFormula()

```
Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Range("C1:C115")

If Cell.Value > 1 And Cell.Value.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
                
    Cell.Value.Offset(2, 0) = "a"
    
End If

 
Next Cell
```

End Sub